# Validation works first time, but not subsequently

Tags: javascript, validation, aurelia

I'm not sure what's missing here. When the site initially loads and I try to submit an empty form, validation kicks in the validation result correctly indicates `valid == false`. I then attempt to validate again, anywhere on the site, and validation always returns `valid == true`. If I refresh the browser, again it works the first time but not afterward.

Inspecting my `ValidationController` instance (`this.validation`) on the initial attempt, `bindings` is filled in. On Subsequent attempts, `bindings` is empty.

Here is an example of how my validation is set up.

**create.ts**

```
import { autoinject} from "aurelia-framework";
import { ValidationController, ValidationRules } from "aurelia-validation";
import { DefaultValidationControllerFactory } from "../../lib/validation/default-validation-controller-factory";
import { Customer } from "../../lib/models/Customer";

@autoinject
export class CreateForm {
    private validation: ValidationController;

    public customer = new Customer();

    constructor(validationControllerFactory: DefaultValidationControllerFactory) {
        this.validation = validationControllerFactory.createForCurrentScope();
    }

    public attached() {
        ValidationRules
            .ensure((o: Customer) => o.firstName)
            .required()
            .ensure((o: Customer) => o.lastName)
            .required()
            .ensure((o: Customer) => o.facebookName)
            .required()
            .ensure((o: Customer) => o.state)
            .required()
            .on(this.customer);
    }

    public createCustomer() {
        this.isBusy = true;

        return this.validation
            .validate()
            .then(result => {
                if (result.valid) {
                    // ...
                }
            })
            .finally(() => {
                this.isBusy = false;
            });
    }
}
```

**create.html**

```
<template>
    <div busy.bind="isBusy" class="form content-area">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>First Name</label>
                            <input value.bind="customer.firstName & validate" type="text" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Last Name</label>
                            <input value.bind="customer.lastName & validate" type="text" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Email Address</label>
                            <input value.bind="customer.emailAddress & validate" type="text" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

**default-validation-controller-factory.ts**

```
import { autoinject } from "aurelia-framework";
import { Validator, ValidationController, ValidationControllerFactory, ValidationRules } from "aurelia-validation";
import { DefaultValidationRenderer } from "./default-validation-renderer";

@autoinject
export class DefaultValidationControllerFactory {
    private validationControllerFactory: ValidationControllerFactory;
    private validationRenderer: DefaultValidationRenderer;

    constructor(validationControllerFactory: ValidationControllerFactory, validationRenderer: DefaultValidationRenderer) {
        this.validationControllerFactory = validationControllerFactory;
        this.validationRenderer = validationRenderer;
    }

    public create(validator?: Validator): ValidationController {
        let validationController = this.validationControllerFactory.create(validator);

        this.setDefaults(validationController);

        return validationController;
    }

    public createForCurrentScope(validator?: Validator): ValidationController {
        let validationController = this.validationControllerFactory.createForCurrentScope(validator);

        this.setDefaults(validationController);

        return validationController;
    }

    private setDefaults(validationController: ValidationController) {
        validationController.addRenderer(this.validationRenderer);
    }
}
```

**default-validation-renderer.ts**

```
import { inject } from "aurelia-dependency-injection";
import { ValidationRenderer, RenderInstruction } from "aurelia-validation";

const ValidationErrorClassName = "validation-error";

@inject(Element)
export class DefaultValidationRenderer implements ValidationRenderer {
    private boundaryElement: HTMLElement;

    constructor(boundaryElement: HTMLElement) {
        this.boundaryElement = boundaryElement;
    }

    public render(instruction: RenderInstruction) {
        for (let item of instruction.unrender) {
            for (let target of item.elements) {
                let messages = target.parentElement.getElementsByClassName(ValidationErrorClassName);

                for (let i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                    let message = messages[i];

                    target.parentElement.removeChild(message);
                }
            }
        }

        for (let item of instruction.render.filter(o => !o.result.valid)) {
            for (let target of item.elements) {
                let message = target.ownerDocument.createElement("div");

                message.classList.add(ValidationErrorClassName);
                message.innerHTML = item.result.message;
                target.parentNode.insertBefore(message, target.nextSibling);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `DefaultValidationControllerFactory`. Replace it for:

```
export class DefaultValidationControllerFactory {

 public static get(container: Container) {
    return new DefaultValidationControllerFactory(container);
  }

  constructor(private container: Container) { }

  public create(validator?: Validator) {
    if (!validator) {
      validator = this.container.get(Validator) as Validator;
    }
    return new ValidationController(validator);
  }

  public createForCurrentScope(validator?: Validator) {
    const controller = this.create(validator);
    controller.addRenderer(new DefaultValidationRenderer());
    this.container.registerInstance(ValidationController, controller);
    return controller;
  }
}

(DefaultValidationControllerFactory as any)['protocol:aurelia:resolver'] = true;
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Well, I don't really know why but it seems that your factory is creating the same instance all the time. So, in the first time it works. In the second time you're getting the same controller instance, so it doesn't work. I'd have to look at the source-code to know exactly why this is happening. Did my answer solve your problem?